# SQL Server Management Studio crash on edit rows

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I don't know why, but past week, SQL Server Management Studio started to crash when I try to use "Edit Top 200 rows" option. It happened with 2014 version, but I have installed 2016 version with the same weird result.

Could be a server related problem? A coworker is working without problems with the same configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the [eventlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) on the computer you are working on. Check `Application` section for the time when SSMS crashed.

Comment: I have checked event log, but there is only an Application Hang error without too much information. It only sais that I should check Maintenance and security history in Control Panel. But there isn't more information in that place.

Comment: Check [this link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118311). Looks like you need to install os/software updates to your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could find out the problem. Visual Studio 2017 messed my computer and broke something. After one of the updates of Visual Studio, Management Studio was repaired too.

Comment: My VS has just updated to 15.4.3 and SSMS's "edit table" is now borked, too.

Answer (score 9):

You need to upgrade to SSMS Version 18.x.

The
[Release Notes for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)
states Bug fixes in 18.0:

> Table Designer    -  Fixed a crash in "Edit 200 rows".

Here V17.9 and V17.9.1 crashed in combination with *SQL Server 2019 Express*.
The server versions *SQL Server 2014 Express* and *SQL Server 2017* was possible to edit with my old SSMS V17.9.1.

After installation of SSMS **V18.4** editing was possible even for *SQL Server **2019** Express*

Comment: I have latest SSMS (18.6) and it is still crashing. Before that I had older v18 version, and it was crashing too.

Comment: I have version 19.2 and it still locks on me daily. I can't figure out it it's something I've done wrong or if SSMS is just a dog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 15.9.8 of VS 2017.  Looks like it's broken again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when one of my columns had the char `"` in it. When I deleted the char `"` from the column name, it stopped crashing when editing.